# Combination AFCI/GFCI breaker with GFCI receptacle

Tags: receptacle, gfci, afci

Is there any issue with having a GFCI receptacle connected (terminally) on a circuit  with a AFCI/GCFI combination breaker?  If not, is there any advantage to having a GFCI outlet on this circuit (wet area)?

Answer (score 4):

There is no advantage and it adds an annoyance factor. Both breaker and GFCI outlet will both trip on ground fault. But the user has to remember the breaker must be reset first.

Comment: Maybe not "both", but it is indeed indeterminate which will trip.  Besides, the breaker is *better* at interrupting faults than the receptacle-GFCI is.

Comment: Mostly anymore I think they both end up tripping, but your right, they "might" not... Still an annoyance factor when the user can't figure out what's happening and why because there are multiple trip points that must be reset in order.   (Reason I think mostly both trip these days comes because I take residential service calls part of the day and often talk people through this stuff) @ThreePhaseEel